# Update Google Docs trigger - once and for all docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a lot of similar spreadsheets in GoogleDocs. There's an `onEdit` trigger in each of them that does some complex validation. Its code is the same for each document, and sometimes I need to update it for all the spreadsheets at one time.

This is what I already tried:

- Install a trigger from one "mother" spreadsheet, i.e.

  ```
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('f_proc').forSpreadsheet(iCurSh).onEdit().create();
  ```

This gives us ability to updatability, but also lots of collisions when executed by several users simultaneously.

- Calling the validation method from library. This gives no collisions, but in case of update I have to change library version manually in each spreadsheet.

Are there any other ways?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried keeping the library in dev mode?  That eliminates the need to change the version manually.

Answer (score 0):

As one comment says above, use libraries in development mode so they always use the latest code without worrying about versions. You can also keep the code somewhere else like a google doc, get it with documentApp and inject it programmatically with 'eval' but might be slower than eval even if you cache it with cache service (I used to do this before gas had libraries)